# Convert identical column of multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops, posix

I have a number of dataframes in the global environment, let's call them `a`, `b`, and `c` .

Each of the dataframes has a column named `start_time` which needs to be converted into posix class, but I am looking for way to do this without writing out the same code for each dataframe.  The code is:

```
 a$start_time <- strptime(a$start_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

That would only convert the `start_time` in `a`

Using the dataframe names, how could one devise a way to loop over each of the dataframes and convert `start_time` to posix?

This attempt with `lapply` only works on the first dataframe...

```
ll <- list(a, b, c)
lapply(ll,function(df){
  df$start_time <- strptime(df$start_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')         

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data: `df1`, `df2`, `df3`

```
df1 <- data.frame(start_time = seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 100, 10))    
df2 <- data.frame(start_time = seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 100, 10))    
df3 <- data.frame(start_time = seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 100, 10))

# create a vector with names of the data frames   
data_vec <- c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')

# loop through the data_vec and modify the start_time column
a1 <- lapply(data_vec, function( x ) {
  x <- get( x )
  x <- within(x, start_time <- strptime(start_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') )
  return( x )
  })

# assign names to the modified data in a1
names(a1) <- data_vec

# list objects in global environment
ls()
# [1] "a1"       "data_vec" "df1"      "df2"      "df3" 

# remove df1, df2, df3 from global environment
rm(list = c('df1', 'df2', 'df3') )

# confirm the removal of data
ls()
# [1] "a1"       "data_vec"

# assign the named list in a1 as data in global environment
list2env(a1, envir = .GlobalEnv)

# list objects in global environment and confirm that the data appeared again
ls()
# [1] "a1"       "data_vec" "df1"      "df2"      "df3"     

# output
head(df1)
#            start_time
# 1 2017-03-03 22:49:54
# 2 2017-03-03 22:50:04
# 3 2017-03-03 22:50:14
# 4 2017-03-03 22:50:24
# 5 2017-03-03 22:50:34
# 6 2017-03-03 22:50:44

head(df2)
#            start_time
# 1 2017-03-03 22:49:54
# 2 2017-03-03 22:50:04
# 3 2017-03-03 22:50:14
# 4 2017-03-03 22:50:24
# 5 2017-03-03 22:50:34
# 6 2017-03-03 22:50:44
```

Comment: interesting workflow, that worked

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's code, the dataset was not returned.  So, it is basically

```
lapply(ll,function(df){
  df$start_time <- strptime(df$start_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')         
  df
})
```

---

But, without returning the object and the anonymous function call, `transform` is an option.  Also, `strptime` returns `POSIXlt` class too.  If we need just `POSIXct`, use the `as.POSIXct`

```
lapply(ll, transform, start_time = as.POSIXct(start_time,  format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Or to make it more compact

```
library(lubridate)
lapply(ll, transform, start_time = ymd_hms(start_time))
```